# Waiting std::condition_variable while forking and forked child process is unable to resume it

Tags: multithreading, c++11, pthreads, fork, condition-variable

I am trying to understand forking with multithreading. So what happens in below scenario ?

- Application thread has spawned a thread - polling thread
- Application thread runs fork
- atpthread_fork handler's pre_fork stops the polling thread using a std::condition_variable. It also waits on a different condition variable to resume the polling
- atpthread_fork handler's post_fork in child does cv.notify_one for the waiting poll thread and stops the poll thread
- atpthread_fork handler's post_fork in parent does cv.notify_one for the waiting poll thread and resumes the poll thread

But what happens is, post_fork in child enters an infinite loop where it keeps on waiting. This also doesn't seem to notified the poll thread cv at all.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: When you read the manpage for `pthread_atfork()`, *which* part of it convinces you that this is a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to understand forking with multithreading.

The #1 thing to understand about combining forking with multithreading is ***don't do it***.  The combination is highly problematic other than in a handful of special cases.

> So what happens in below scenario ?
>
> - Application thread has spawned a thread - polling thread
> - Application thread runs fork
> - atpthread_fork handler's pre_fork stops the polling thread using a std::condition_variable. It also waits on a different condition
>   variable to resume the polling

That makes no sense.  A condition variable does not have the power to preemptively make any thread stop.  And if the polling thread eventually did stop by blocking on the CV, then what role would a different CV have to play in starting it again?

> - atpthread_fork handler's post_fork in child does cv.notify_one for the waiting poll thread and stops the poll thread

I suppose you meant to say that a post_fork handler registered via *`pthread_atfork`* performs a `cv.notify_one` in the child to *resume* the poll thread.

Any way around, it is impossible for the child to do anything with the polling thread because it doesn't have one.  The child process has only one thread -- a copy of the one that called `fork()`.  This is one of the main reasons why forking and multithreading don't mix.

> - atpthread_fork handler's post_fork in parent does cv.notify_one for the waiting poll thread and resumes the poll thread

This seems questionable in light of the overall questionable behavior you are attributing to the CVs, but there is nothing inherently wrong with the concept.

> But what happens is, post_fork in child enters an infinite loop where
> it keeps on waiting.

Something is missing here.  Are you doing a *timed* wait?  Is its wait failing?  These are the only ways I can think of that the child could be both looping and waiting.  There is initially no other thread in the child process to wake the single one that resulted from the fork, so that thread cannot perform a successful return from a wait on any CV, unless spurriously. There is no one to signal it.

> This also doesn't seem to notified the poll
> thread cv at all.

Do you mean the one in the child that doesn't exist?  Or the one in the parent that probably isn't waiting on the CV you think it's waiting on?

---

Most of the above is moot.  There is absolutely no reason to think that your program is exercising one of the special exceptions, so refer to #1: don't combine forking with multithreading.  Choose *one*.